# Dump of BAMs (Broadcast Announcement Message) with canutils

Tags: can-bus, socketcan, j1939, canutils

Good morning, 
I'm a embedded linux developer and I'm trying to dump J1939 CAN sentences on a iMX6 based board.

I tried saving RAW canbus messages on a file using the command

**candump can0  -L > /tmp/fms_canbus**

and *everything works fine with NON BROADCAST messages*.

However I'm not able to receive BROADCAST messages (BAM), it seems that no BAM message is recorded on the file.

As far as I know, in order to read BAM message, the socket should be opened with option SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM, but it seems there is no CLI tool in canutils package that allows to perform an operation similar to the

**candump can0  -L > /tmp/fms_canbus**

Is there anyone that can help me fixing this issue?
Should I implement a custom tool or is there a standard utils allowing to perform the desired action?
Best regards
Giovanni